# identity server 4 as a API and web project

Tags: .net, identityserver4

I'm planing a micro-service project using .net core web api and about to use identity server for authentication . since there is mobile based clients (android,ios) how can i use identity server login as a web project and  other functions like registration,email confirmation , password reset etc  via API endpoint

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are planning to use ASP.Net CORE Identity as your identity store. Take a look at IdentityServer4's tutorial projects (https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/quickstarts/). It has sample code for authentication. As for identity admin functions, IdentityServer doesn't have those functions built in as far as I know. you need to create your own. But there are some good references out there, such as this https://code-maze.com/asp-net-core-identity-series/.

Comment: Yes. He is right. You need to write those APIs. Check my code base where there's a code to register a user via API https://snipboard.io/ZR9Gt1.jpg

Comment: yes i was tried to use .net core identity and identityserver in same project